# Почему не отправляется сообщение?

Tags: c#, сокет

Всем привет, я наконец-то смог сделать сервер, к которому может подключаться много клиентов, но теперь проблема в другом, как отправить сообщение? При отправке появляется ошибка:

> Запрос на отправку или получение данных  (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Код сервера:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4001));

    sck.Listen(0);

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 4000);
    TcpClient client = null;

    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        using (client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Подключен новый клиент");

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("бла блал бла");

            sck.Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            sck.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4001);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient ("127.0.0.1", 4000);

            if (client.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подключено");

                byte[] buff = new byte[255];

                int num = sck.Receive(buff);

                string message = Encoding.Default.GetString(buff);

                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Так отправлять-то надо через client (результат accept'а). В примере http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclient.aspx обмен идёт через stream этого сокета

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, вы смешали сокеты и более высокоуровневые `TcpListener` и `TcpClient`. Рискну предположить, что `sck` вам не нужен совсем. В коде сервера вы должны отправлять сообщения клиенту через объект `client`, в коде клиента - использовать объект `client` для получения данных.

Ошибка возникает, потому что вы пытаетесь отправить данные через сокет, который настроен только как слушатель входящих подключений.

Answer (score 0):

Надо устанавливать свойства Таймаут на Ресив и Сенд. Например 3000 мсек..